# How to see my full Arqade post history?

Tags: support

Considering that [Stack Exchange automatically deletes "dead" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) and deleted questions/answers are removed from user profiles after a certain time period (30 days?), active long-time users likely have lost some of their content unless they manually keep track of URLs. How can I access my complete post history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Exchange has recently made [some changes that allow users to see their full deleted question and answer history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374184), regardless of how long ago the post was deleted.

There's a list for both questions and answers. You can navigate to these pages yourself by opening your [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=questions) and [answers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=answers) pages, scrolling to the bottom, and clicking the "Deleted questions" or "Deleted answers" link, which will take you to a page for that post type.

The direct links to these pages are:

- Answers: `gaming.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-answers/current` ([link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-answers/current))
- Questions: `gaming.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current` ([link](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current))

Though this addition makes your deleted posts more visible regardless of reputation, the `deleted:1` search operator still requires having earned the [access to moderator tools](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege.

Answer (score 0):

You can search Arqade's automated bot [Lazers 2.0's](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-356/lazers-2-0) post history by appending your username to the search field:

[image: Lazers 2.0]

Because the bot doesn't share answers, you have to contact a moderator or a user with over 10 000 reputation (see [user privileges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)) to access your full history.